# Error with Symfony chain routeur

Tags: php, symfony, ezplatform

i'm working on a Back office with Ez-platform 1.8 and Symfony 2.8.

I use this back office for mobile application. My api is responding very well.

I just have a huge problem with simultaneous request.

Let me explain :
  - On my first page on the mobile application i need to retreive 2 feeds at the same times.
  - When i do thoses calls at the same time, my server is responding a 200OK to my http request but with this answer instead of my JSON :

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' with message 'None of the routers in the chain matched this request
GET /_fos_user_context_hash HTTP/1.0
Accept:               application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash
Accept-Charset:       ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:      gzip
Accept-Language:      en-us,en;q=0.5
Authorization:        
Connection:           close
Host:                 test.dev.test.com
Surrogate-Capability: symfony2=&quot;ESI/1.0&quot;
User-Agent:           okhttp/3.5.0
X-Forwarded-For:      172.16.100.147
X-Php-Ob-Level:       1
' in /home/www-data/test/releases/1.0.0-d3787bc1/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/ChainRouter.php:207
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www-data/test/releases/1.0.0-d3787bc1/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/ChainRouter.php(156): Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ChainRouter-&gt;doMatch('/_fos_user_cont...', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#1 /home/www-data/test/releases/1.0.0-d3787bc1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Co in <b>/home/www-data/test/releases/1.0.0-d3787bc1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php</b> on line <b>95</b><br />
```

But when i delay those 2 calls the server responds me my json.

Do you know why and how i can fix that ?

Thanks.

Edit :

The url i'm calling :
first feed : 
https://test.dev.test.com/apimobile/slides

```
[  
   {  
      "id":65,
      "title":"Slide 1",
      "subtitle":"subtitle 1",
      "image":"https:\/\/test.dev.test.com\/var\/site\/storage\/images\/5\/1\/2\/0\/215-1-eng-GB\/home02.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "id":66,
      "title":"Slide 2",
      "subtitle":"subtitle 2",
      "image":"https:\/\/test.dev.test.com\/var\/site\/storage\/images\/5\/1\/2\/0\/215-1-eng-GB\/home01.jpg"
   }
]
```

second feed :
https://test.dev.test.com/apimobile/news

```
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "date": "16/03/2017",
        "category": "Catégorie 1",
        "title": "Actu 2",
        "shortContent": "short description actu 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 64,
        "date": "16/03/2017",
        "category": "Catégorie 2",
        "title": "Actu 3",
        "shortContent": "short description actu 3"
    },
    {
        "id": 62,
        "date": "16/03/2017",
        "category": "Catégorie 1",
        "title": "Actu 1",
        "shortContent": "short description actu 1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please give more insight? What are those feeds? Could you provide URL examples please?
It seems to come from user context hash request. Are you using Varnish or Symfony reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes of course i edit my question with urls and feed.

Comment: Thanks.
You didn't answer to my question about Varnish or Symfony reverse proxy. This is important :-)

Comment: Sorry, i'm using ezplatform-http-cache so by default the Symfony reverse proxy

Comment: I have made one more test, In local with my vagrant machine the server always respond well but in prod i have the probelm i have describe right in top